# How to compile printer driver?

Tags: raspbian, driver, software-compilation

I installed CUPS on raspbian but while adding The printer the driver/ppd file for Epson L210 series is not available and neither on epson website the driver/ppd file for armh is available , I guess that i will have to compile the driver but don't know how to do it , Please someone guide me , thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unless you can find source code for the driver you cannot compile it.  This is a problem with proprietary software.  Printer manufacturers seem to be especially bad about it.  You may have paid them for the printer but that does not give you the right to use it as you wish ;)

Comment: I found the printer src and compiled it but CUPS gives an error that printer filter directory not found/no such directory found.

Comment: I tried printing by selecting other epson series driver that i found but it just prints random characters as its not the driver of that printer , as per gutenprint the driver is present in the latest build of gutenprint but when i try to update CUPS it says its on latest version . Is there any way of download gutenprint driver seperately from there website??

Comment: The latest version available through Raspbian will probably be behind the latest version available independently, as Raspbian is essentially [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) which has a conservative policy about versioning (the idea being that not using the latest of everything makes the system more stable).  You could try building and installing gutenprint, but I can't say how complicated that may or may not be (I barely ever use a printer for anything).

Comment: I haven't looked at it, but you want the `.tar.bz2` file from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.2/5.2.12/  You can unpack that `tar -xjf ...` and it will expand into a folder, likely there will be further instructions inside.  Since the archive is only 7 MB, it is probably not that time consuming to compile on a Pi.

Comment: Thanks very much I will try and report if it works or not

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing the raspi repo to an unstable and latest repo and then updated cups from 1.7.5 to 2.2.1 and than updated gutenprint drivers and ppd files and now its working smoothly thanks for your help

Comment: If you have time please leave an answer of your own :)